# How to disable database name appending to in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

The problem is that I use a few identical databases with different names. I would like `ConnectionDBContext` designer not to append database name to functions name. For instance

`[Function(Name=@"**project.**DeletePlnAttributeSelectableValue", IsComposable=true)]`

where "project" is the database name. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.
Paweł

Answer (score 2):

The database name **isn't** prepended; that is the **schema** (historically: owner, but a bit more complex) of the object. It will not work without the schema, **especially** for a UDF, where it is a mandatory part of the calling syntax in TSQL.

By which I mean that:

```
select * from DeletePlnAttributeSelectableValue(...)
```

is **not** valid TSQL; it must include the schema, for example:

```
select * from dbo.DeletePlnAttributeSelectableValue(...)
```

The database would be *before* that; multi-part object naming is:

```
[[[server].][[database].][schema].]object
```

so `foo` is an object called `foo`, and `somedb..foo` is `foo` in the `somedb` database.

I *suspect* the problem here is that you have chosen the "default schema" for the database on a per-database basis, which is a bad design, IMO.

A LINQ data-context works just fine against any database with appropriate objects - you simply supply the connection-string (or connection) at runtime via the constructor.